# Devise Password Reset find by Email and Subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-recoverable

My App has logins uniqe to each Account, where accounts have a subdomain.

I then override the find_for_authentication method in the User  model. I got this method from the [wiki](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain):    This works great for logins.

However,  user from one subdomain can send a reset from other subdomains, because the find_for_authentication method is not used for that.

How can I restrict the password reset functionality to find only users for that account/subdomain?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?